# How to create virtualenv with specific site-wide installed libraries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I would like to know if it is possible to create virtual environments that only
using certain system installed libraries.

For examples I have scipy, numpy and matplotlib installed system-wide.

I would like to create virtual environments that use them, but not all the system wide libraries. The download and compiling takes a while every time I install them using pip,
plus they occupy space and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: try this option while creating virtual envs: `--no-site-packages`; btw, you could create soft links for those system-wide libraries.